# Positioning icons on paper-toolbar in Polymer

Tags: polymer, toolbar

I want to be able to place the paper-icon-button to the right/end of the paper-toolbar. This is what I have tried.

```
<paper-toolbar class="toolbar" justify="end">
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    <span class="title">{{page}}</span>
    <paper-icon-button  icon="check-box" class="justify"></paper-icon-button>
</paper-toolbar>
```

I have tried with middle-justify and bottom-justify too. The effect currently is they are placed side by side

Also I have tried the demo here https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-toolbar?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-toolbar

cant achieve that effect.

Any suggestions or examples thanks.

Comment: Your current code already renders the "checkbox" button on the righthand side of the toolbar. Are you saying you want both `paper-icon-button`s to be aligned to the right?

Comment: no just the checkbox. It was not showing up unfortunately, I am not sure why. So I managed to do through css.

Comment: For reference, here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ezmrqv?editors=1000) with your original code working without any modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [iron-flex-layout](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-flex-layout?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-flex-layout). Import it and then add the `class="flex"` to the `<span>`

Comment: Thanks. Yes this works. I managed to do it through css before, but now this is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try float:right css property on your paper-icon-buttons